# What Changed in webapi2 that stops shared bearer token decryption?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2, owin, bearer-token

I have a special requirement for 2 api's that use the same database. If I make a project using the default template in VS2013 and pass it the access token from the other api on the same machine it will decrypt it properly and load up the user. However the second I open the nuget package manager console and type "Update-Package" to update all the template's packages it no longer decrypts the access token and returns unauthorized access?

I'd like to update it before I gut all the template bloat from it. What changed and is there a way to code it so it works properly after I update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally just resolved this problem this weekend. My guess is that you updated from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1 (talking about `Microsoft.Owin.Security`).

The assembly contains a class called `TokenSerializer`. If you decompile the code, you will see that it has an internal format version. In 3.0.0, the internal format was "2". In 3.0.1, they bumped the internal format version to "3". This causes the `.Deserialize` method to bail. Beyond the stupidity of breaking semantic versioning, the serialization and deserialization methods are identical which means that they *could have* changed the code to accept both formats *or* implemented a migration for us.

What I ended up doing was inlining the 3.0.0 version of the code as a new class (since I can't host both assemblies in the same process and standing up a new process was too much trouble) and I just manually try to deserialize both. Works fine but sure is nasty.

**Update with code:**

```
public class RefreshTokenTicketRepository : AzureTableStorageRepository<RefreshTokenTicketDto>, IRefreshTokenTicketRepository
{
    private static readonly TicketSerializer _ticketSerializer = new TicketSerializer();
    private static readonly TicketSerializer_v2 _ticketSerializer_v2 = new TicketSerializer_v2();
    private const string tableName = "refreshtokentickets";
    public const string PartitionKey = "refreshtokentickets";

    public enum SerializationFormatVersion
    {
        vCurrent,
        v2,
        Unknown
    }

    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RefreshTokenTicketRepository(IHoursTrackerCloudStorageAccountFactory storageAccountFactory, ILogger logger)
        : base(storageAccountFactory, tableName)
    {
        _logger = logger.ForContext<RefreshTokenTicketRepository>();
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationTicket> GetAsync(string refreshToken)
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("Refresh Token", refreshToken))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
            {
                _logger.Debug("Null or empty refresh token");
                return null;
            }

            RefreshTokenTicketDto refreshTokenTicketDto = await GetAsync(PartitionKey, refreshToken);

            if (refreshTokenTicketDto == null)
            {
                _logger.Debug("Authentication ticket not found");
                return null;
            }

            SerializationFormatVersion version;
            AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = Deserialize(refreshTokenTicketDto.RefreshTokenTicket, out version);

            if (authenticationTicket != null && version != SerializationFormatVersion.vCurrent)
            {
                _logger.Information("Updating authentication ticket serialization format from {Version}", version);
                await InsertOrReplaceAsync(new RefreshTokenTicketDto(refreshToken, _ticketSerializer.Serialize(authenticationTicket)));
            }

            return authenticationTicket;
        }
    }

    public Task PersistAsync(string refreshToken, AuthenticationTicket refreshTokenTicket)
    {
        return PersistAsync(new RefreshTokenTicketDto(refreshToken, _ticketSerializer.Serialize(refreshTokenTicket)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// In Microsoft.Owin.Security 3.0.1, Microsoft changed the internal version format from 2 to 3.
    /// This caused the TokenSerializer to return null for otherwise valid AuthenticationTickets.
    /// So we decompiled the v2 implementation and inlined it below and update the the bytes to reflect v3.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authenticationTicketBytes"></param>
    /// <param name="version">The version of the AuthenticationTicket</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public AuthenticationTicket Deserialize(byte[] authenticationTicketBytes, out SerializationFormatVersion version)
    {
        _logger.Debug("Deserializing authentication ticket");

        AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = _ticketSerializer.Deserialize(authenticationTicketBytes);
        if (authenticationTicket != null)
        {
            version = SerializationFormatVersion.vCurrent;
            _logger.Debug("Authentication ticket version is {Version}", version);
            return authenticationTicket;
        }

        authenticationTicket = _ticketSerializer_v2.Deserialize(authenticationTicketBytes);
        if (authenticationTicket != null)
        {
            version = SerializationFormatVersion.v2;
            _logger.Debug("Authentication ticket version is {Version}", version);
            return authenticationTicket;
        }

        version = SerializationFormatVersion.Unknown;
        _logger.Debug("Authentication ticket version is {Version}", version);
        return null;
    }

    public byte[] Serialize(AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket)
    {
        return _ticketSerializer.Serialize(authenticationTicket);
    }

    public byte[] Serialize_v2(AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket)
    {
        return _ticketSerializer_v2.Serialize(authenticationTicket);
    }

    #region Decompiled Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer from Microsoft.Owin.Security 3.0.0

    private class TicketSerializer_v2 : IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>
    {
        private const int FormatVersion = 2;

        public byte[] Serialize(AuthenticationTicket model)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
                {
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(gzipStream))
                    {
                        Write(writer, model);
                    }
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Deserialize(byte[] data)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(gzipStream))
                    {
                        return Read(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Write(BinaryWriter writer, AuthenticationTicket model)
        {
            if (writer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
            }
            if (model == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
            }
            writer.Write(FormatVersion);
            ClaimsIdentity identity = model.Identity;
            writer.Write(identity.AuthenticationType);
            WriteWithDefault(writer, identity.NameClaimType, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name");
            WriteWithDefault(writer, identity.RoleClaimType, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role");
            writer.Write(identity.Claims.Count());
            foreach (Claim claim in identity.Claims)
            {
                WriteWithDefault(writer, claim.Type, identity.NameClaimType);
                writer.Write(claim.Value);
                WriteWithDefault(writer, claim.ValueType, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string");
                WriteWithDefault(writer, claim.Issuer, "LOCAL AUTHORITY");
                WriteWithDefault(writer, claim.OriginalIssuer, claim.Issuer);
            }
            var bootstrapContext = identity.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;
            if (bootstrapContext == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bootstrapContext.Token))
            {
                writer.Write(0);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(bootstrapContext.Token.Length);
                writer.Write(bootstrapContext.Token);
            }
            PropertiesSerializer.Write(writer, model.Properties);
        }

        private static AuthenticationTicket Read(BinaryReader reader)
        {
            if (reader == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
            }
            if (reader.ReadInt32() != FormatVersion)
            {
                return null;
            }
            string authenticationType = reader.ReadString();
            string str1 = ReadWithDefault(reader, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name");
            string roleType = ReadWithDefault(reader, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role");
            int length = reader.ReadInt32();
            var claimArray = new Claim[length];
            for (var index = 0; index != length; ++index)
            {
                string type = ReadWithDefault(reader, str1);
                string str2 = reader.ReadString();
                string valueType = ReadWithDefault(reader, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string");
                string str3 = ReadWithDefault(reader, "LOCAL AUTHORITY");
                string originalIssuer = ReadWithDefault(reader, str3);
                claimArray[index] = new Claim(type, str2, valueType, str3, originalIssuer);
            }
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimArray, authenticationType, str1, roleType);
            if (reader.ReadInt32() > 0)
            {
                identity.BootstrapContext = new BootstrapContext(reader.ReadString());
            }
            AuthenticationProperties properties = PropertiesSerializer.Read(reader);
            return new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
        }

        private static void WriteWithDefault(BinaryWriter writer, string value, string defaultValue)
        {
            if (string.Equals(value, defaultValue, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                writer.Write("\0");
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(value);
            }
        }

        private static string ReadWithDefault(BinaryReader reader, string defaultValue)
        {
            string a = reader.ReadString();
            if (string.Equals(a, "\0", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            return a;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Sounds like something Microsoft would do to me... Would it be possible to see the class you made? It's ok if not but it'd save me a lot of time testing this out.

Comment: Yes, but I won't be able to access the code until tonight. Would've posted it otherwise. I'll update my answer later on.

Comment: since you're in the same boat I don't suppose you can answer this one too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828661/azure-hosted-api-bearer-tokens-wont-decrypt-with-context-deserializeticket