# Azure hosted api bearer tokens wont decrypt with context.DeserializeTicket?

Tags: azure, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin, bearer-token

I have 2 webapi2 projects that use the same database. If I'm on localhost I get a bearer token from one I can pass it to the other and the other will properly decrypt it and load the user. However when I publish them to separate urls on azure, I get the one token fine from one but when I pass it to the other I can't get the ticket to load and it gives me the unauthorized response.

I'm testing this by watching the owin AuthenticationTokenProvider.OnRecieve method. When context.DeserializeTicket is called the ticket remains null and the user never gets loaded.

Your first response will likely be about how the machine keys need to be the same between the 2 so they will work. The problem there is

1. All my online research says that azure machine keys are synced between apps in the same role (ones a web app and the other is a web api app) so this shouldn't be an issue
2. I can't specify a machine key because the first app has been in production for a while and changing it's machine key would mess up stored passwords etc...
3. using the machine key used by the production app on the new api nay work but there is no way to get the machine key of an azure web app.

I'm pretty sure this isn't a machine key issue though but I have no idea how to figure this out. Heeeeelllp!

Comment: Have you been able to get any specific errors/logs when you get the unauthorized error?

Comment: No. It's not throwing an error. context.DeserializeTicket simply doesn't set the ticket, thus the user identity is never loaded leaving it unauthorized.

Comment: @DasAmigo How do you have your token verification configured? Also, I'd recommend using x509 certs over machine keys. Solves the problem in a more consistent manner where you do have control and flexibility.

Comment: If the older application used x509 wouldn't that invalidate any stored user passwords just like changing the machine key? I'm not sure what your looking for in verification, I could write a lot about that you'll have to be more specific.  Again it works locally just not when published to separate domains in azure. We have an oauth server in an azure webapp that poops out bearer tokens but I need those tokens to decrypt and load the user in an azure webapi  hosted in the same resource group in azure.

Comment: The idea being, I don't want 3rd party apps that use either of our api's to have to get and manage 2 separate tokens. They already get one and use it for the original api, I'd like them to just pass it to the second api if they need stuff from it as well.